# SQL command will not redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, webforms

I created this slice of code but not behaving the way that it should.

What should happen is when the query returns a matching value in the database, it should redirect the page.  But no matter what I do, it always returns the value as false, and never redirects correctly.

At least that what I think is going on, any help would be great..

I've been working on this for 3 days and I'm about to lose my mind. If there is a better way of doing this I am all ears.

```
var SuserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;

conn.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "select Count(ID) from AspNetStripeUsers where ID=@ID";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", SuserId);

int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

string wewe = result.ToString();

if (wewe == SuserId)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Services/MS/OT/igive");
}
```

Comment: I can't get what you trying to do, you compare the `no of records` to `SuserId`? Should you just check the `result` is greater than 0?

Comment: result.ToString() is number of records and you are trying to compare it to actual user identity.

Comment: It seems that you should modify your sql query to return the user identity or other value fro DB, if any and compare that value to User identity in code. Right now, you are just returning count of records which seems wrong..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();`
will always returns a int value which is not be similar to the userID because it will retrieve the first value from Database so just check whether it has any value which means your condition is true

so the above code which is given by Nayan is true.

```
if (result>0)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Services/MS/OT/igive");
}
else
{
Console.Writeline("The user id is not valid";

}
```

Comment: I see what i was doing wrong. I was using the operator totally wrong because i was over thinking its function. There were records but i was thinking in terms of finding a similar one vs counting all the ones that were like my value. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are comparing UserId and count of UserId which might creating problem.

```
int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

if (result>0)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Services/MS/OT/igive");
}
else
{
//User not registered.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

if (result>0)
{
    Response.Redirect("");
}
```